# Laravel: How to limit subquery many-to-many when use pivot

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot, subquery

I have model `IgAccount`, which hasMany model `IgPost` 
Then I have model `IgHashtag` which is connected via pivot table to `IgPost`

My pivot table is  `ig_hashtag_ig_post`

Now, i want to get all `IgHashtag` whereHas `IgPost` which belongsTo user's  `IgAccount`
and I want to also load this with last 4 `IgPost`, for each `IgHashtag`

I have query like:

```
  $igHashtags = IgHashtag::with(['igposts' => function ($query) use ($igAccount) {
        $query->where('ig_posts.ig_account_id', $igAccount->id) // filter posts for each hashtag, where posts belongsTo hashtag AND only user's ig_account
            ->select('media_url')
            ->orderByDesc('from_ig_timestamp');
        //->take(4); //Not working as expected, this take 4 posts for whole collection, I need 4 posts for each hashtag
    }])->whereHas('igposts', function ($query) use ($igAccount) {
        $query->where('ig_account_id', $igAccount->id); //filter only hashtags, which belongsTo posts which belongsTo users ig account
    })
        ->withCount(['igposts' => function ($query) use ($igAccount) {
            $query->where('ig_posts.ig_account_id', $igAccount->id);
        }])

        ->orderByDesc('igposts_count')->paginate(10);
```

This `->take(4)` loads 4 posts but for whole collection. In result, one hashtag has 2 loaded posts and another two 2 loaded post, others zero. And I need 4 posts for each hashtag:

```
0:Object
hashtag:"fotimGalaxy"
id:3578
igposts:Array[1]
igposts_count:44
1:Object
hashtag:"dnesfotim"
id:3576
igposts:Array[2]
igposts_count:30
2:Object
hashtag:"BLINNKER"
id:3762
igposts:Array[0]
igposts_count:13
3:Object
hashtag:"dnesJem"
id:3575
igposts:Array[1]
igposts_count:12
```

when `->take(4)` is removed from code, works as expected, but it load ALL available Posts for each IgHashtag, right filtered:

```
data:Array[10]
0:Object
hashtag:"fotimGalaxy"
id:3578
igposts:Array[44]
igposts_count:44
1:Object
hashtag:"dnesfotim"
id:3576
igposts:Array[30]
igposts_count:30
2:Object
hashtag:"BLINNKER"
id:3762
igposts:Array[13]
igposts_count:13
3:Object
hashtag:"dnesJem"
id:3575
igposts:Array[12]
igposts_count:12
```

How to query this with last 4 posts for each hashtags?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this after fixing the names. BTW, it's really a bad idea to give everything the same prefix.

```
Hastag::with('posts', function($query) {
   $query->where('account_id', Auth::id())->latest()->limit(4)
})->get()->filter(function($hastag, $key) {
   return $hastag->posts->count() > 0
});
```

Comment: This also not working as expected. This solution only filter results with 0 hashtag. But I need last 4 posts for EACH hashtag (if exists). They exists, as you can see in my question. If there is no 'limit(4)' in my code, every hashtags has posts like posts_count.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.
It is not elegant, but it works as expected.

```
 $igHashtags = IgHashtag::whereHas('igposts', function ($query) use ($igAccount) {
            $query->where('ig_account_id', $igAccount->id); //filter only hashtags, which belongsTo posts which belongsTo users ig account
        })
            ->withCount(['igposts' => function ($query) use ($igAccount) {
                $query->where('ig_posts.ig_account_id', $igAccount->id);
            }])
            ->orderByDesc('igposts_count')->paginate(10);

        $igHashtags->getCollection()->transform(function ($value) use ($igAccount) {
            $value->igposts = IgHashtag::where('id', $value->id)
                ->first()
                ->IgPosts()
                ->select('caption', 'media_url')
                ->where('ig_account_id', $igAccount->id)
                ->orderByDesc('from_ig_timestamp')
                ->take(4)
                ->get();
            return $value;
        });
```